# unable to read http status code in ansible

Tags: ansible

Team,

My goal is to see if status code 403 is present in register variable and then do IF and ELSE. But my "Validate http status code" is not getting evaluated..

```
      - name: "Validate KubeAPI Authentication response as DNS resolve worked"
        uri:
          url: 'https://{{ kubeapi_server }}'
          return_content: yes
          validate_certs: no
        register: uri_output

      - name: "Validate http status code"
        debug:
          msg: "Received 403"
        when: uri_output.status == 403
```

Received output:

```
PLAY [Test connectivity to target servers] ***************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************
ok: [target1]

TASK [DNS test] ***************************************************************************
changed: [target1]

TASK [Validate DNS server] **************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => {
    "msg": "Resolved DNS server 'test.co.com' '24.41.2.5' "
}

TASK [Validate KubeAPI Authentication response as DNS resolve worked] ***************************************************************************
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"audit_id": "59322028-16a5-4c5e-8452-6fcdd308d8d2", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\"forbidden: User \\\"system:anonymous\\\" cannot get path \\\"/\\\"\",\"reason\":\"Forbidden\",\"details\":{},\"code\":403}\n", "content_length": "185", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Thu, 26 Sep 2019 01:12:45 GMT", "json": {"apiVersion": "v1", "code": 403, "details": {}, "kind": "Status", "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"", "metadata": {}, "reason": "Forbidden", "status": "Failure"}, "msg": "Status code was not [200]: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden", "redirected": false, "status": 403, "url": "https://testme.co.com", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff"}


PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************
target1                    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

expected output in end should have this last line.

```
Received 403
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `uri` module expects a HTTP 200 or it will fail and end the play. You will need to do one of two things to ensure your play continues past this task (so that you can then validate the status).

Either ignore any and all errors:

```
      - name: "Validate KubeAPI Authentication response as DNS resolve worked"
        uri:
          url: 'https://{{ kubeapi_server }}'
          return_content: yes
          validate_certs: no
        ignore_errors: yes
        register: uri_output
```

Or add all allowed HTTP status codes:

```
      - name: "Validate KubeAPI Authentication response as DNS resolve worked"
        uri:
          url: 'https://{{ kubeapi_server }}'
          return_content: yes
          validate_certs: no
          status_code:
            - 200
            - 403
        register: uri_output
```